# Jenkins: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$' found among steps [ArtifactoryGradleBuild, MavenDescript

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

`db2storage = (${STORAGE} * 1024)`

Get the above error.
Not sure if the syntax is wrong or what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to remove the `$` and brackets as it is not needed.

```
def STORAGE = 10
def db2storage = STORAGE * 1024
```

**EDIT** :
If the STORAGE is a string parameter , then you could use as below:
`def db2storage = Integer.parseInt(params.STORAGE) * 1024`

Comment: Its taken from a string parameter. Is that not correct?                                                                                                                                                                   string(name: 'STORAGE', defaultValue: '20', description: 'Standard plan storage values in 20GB increments MAX 4000GB eg input 20 up to 4000 ')'

Comment: @ChrisBoyd , then you could use ``def db2storage = Integer.parseInt(params.STORAGE)  * 1024``. I have updated the answer with this info.

Comment: Cheers that was it